# Adding multiple mime types and file extensions in Drive UI Integration in API Manager

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-developers-console

Is it possible to combine multiple mime types and file extensions in the API manager while Drive UI Integration.

Ho do I add Default extensions, adding one by one is tedious.

[image]

Comment: add them one by one.  I am curious as to why this is a problem.

Comment: If " * / * " doesn't work, do as DalmTo says.